# Accessing the solr folder folder from multiple server instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-solr

AWS has just announced general availability of its EFS (Elastic File System). It allows you to create a network drive that can be shared by multiple AWS instances.

I have a Rails application, using sunspot-solr gem. A solr folder is created to store the solr index file and other related data.

The MySQL data is on its own RDS instance. I want to deploy two servers, both running the same Rails application, but have them both point to the same solr folder on the shared EFS share.

Assuming that both servers running the Rails app, are using the same solr gem version, will my scenario work, or will each server need its own solr folder?

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting up Solr as its own server, separate from the Rails apps?

Comment: I have only used solr in conjunction with Rails. So, if I set up a separate Solr server, separate from the Rails app, the Rails app will still be able to use the common Solr data? I will need to read up on this, so if you have some pointers, that would be great.

Comment: That gem was intended to be used in development / testing (https://rubygems.org/gems/sunspot_solr). I suggest you keep and boot your own solr instance or migrate elasticsearch which AWS provides as a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the version of Solr packed with the development version of Sunspot is a separate Solr server that Rails communicates with. So in production, you are responsible for providing a Solr server for these purposes, be it on one of your EC2 instances or on its own separate EC2 instance.

A little more info... Rails posts data for Solr to consume via Sunspot, but the Solr server handles those details, not your Ruby app. Therefore, sharing the Solr data files with Rails won't provide you with any advantage.

When I was getting started, I hooked my Heroku-hosted Rails app up to [Websolr](https://websolr.com/) if you think that $20+ per month would be worth it. Otherwise, look up tips for installing Solr on EC2.